# Simple bitwise operation in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

I'm writing code in Java using short typed variables. Short variables are normally 16 bits but unfortunately Java doesn't have unsigned primitive types so I'm using the 15 lower bits instead ignoring the sign bit. Please don't suggest changes to this part as I'm already quite far in this implementation... Here is my question:

I have a variable which I need to XOR.

In C++ I would just write

```
myunsignedshort = myunsignedshort ^ 0x2000;

0x2000 (hex) = 0010000000000000 (binary)
```

However, in Java, I have to deal with the sign bit also so I'm trying to change my mask so that it doesn't affect the xor...

```
mysignedshort = mysignedshort ^ 0xA000;

0xA000 (hex) = 1010000000000000 (binary)
```

This isn't having the desired effect and I'm not sure why. Anyone can see where I'm going wrong?

Regards.

EDIT: ok you guys are right, that bit wasn't causing the issue.

the issue comes when I'm shifting bits to the left.

I accidentally shift bits into the sign bit.

mysignedshort = mysignedshort << 1;

Any any ideas how to avoid this new prob so that if it shifts into the MSB then nothing happens at all? or should I just do a manual test? Theres a lot of this shifting in the code though so I would prefer a more terse solution.

Regards.

Comment: Whenever you need the variable without the sign, just do a `mysignedshort & 0x7FFFFFFF`.

Comment: So... mysignedshort = (mysignedshort & 0x7FFFFFFF) ^ 0xA000;

Comment: That could work, but as long as you sticking to XOR, AND, OR and logical shifts, you could just ignore it. Then just remove it when it would absolutely need to not be there.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `^ 0x2000` will do the same thing on a signed short as it will on an unsigned one. I don't understand why you think flipping the MSB will help.

Comment: In general, if a Java integer contains the bit pattern you want you can `and` and `or` and `xor` it to your heart's content and no sign extension will occur.  The only time sign extension occurs is when a `byte` or `short` value is extended to `int` length to do computations (since computations are only carried out in `int` or `long` precision), and if you cast it back to `byte` or `short` the extended bits will go bye-bye.

Comment: (And note that "unsigned short" in Java is called `char` and will extend to `int` without sign extension.)

Comment: (In other words, you're over-thinking it.  No extra bit twiddling or masking should be required.)

Comment: yeah you guys were totally correct, I had identified the wrong area of code. Its actually the shifting to the left as explained in the question. Any ideas on the variation of my original problem?

Comment: If you're ignoring the sign bit, why do you care what gets shifted into it?

Comment: I perform inequality checks on th variables. <, > etc

Answer (score 0):

Those operations don't care about signedness, as mentioned in the comments. But I can expand on that.

Operations for which the signed and unsigned versions are the same:

- addition/subtraction
- and/or/xor
- multiplication
- left shift
- equality testing

Operations for which they are different:

- division/remainder
- right shift, there's `>>` and `>>>`
- ordered comparison, you can make `a < b` as `(a ^ 0x80000000) < (b ^ 0x80000000)` to change from signed to unsigned, or unsigned to signed.
  You can also use `(a & 0xffffffffL) < (b & 0xffffffffL)` to get an unsigned comparison, but that doesn't generalize to longs.